# jquery infinite loop (to move a div position)

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-loop

I have the following jquery code to move a rectangle from one place to another. It works.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        loop_pos = function () {
            var docHeight = $(document).height(),
                docWidth = $(document).width(),
                $div = $('#test'),
                divWidth = $div.width(),
                divHeight = $div.height(),
                heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
                widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

            $div.css({
                left: Math.floor(Math.random() * widthMax),
                top: Math.floor(Math.random() * heightMax)
                // here
            });
        }
        // or here
    });
});
```

Now, I want to make this rectangle change its position automatically in a infinite loop.
I tried to call the function loop_pos, in //here also // or here, but it doesn't work and I don't know how to do it.

Another solution maybe setTimeout() but I can't make  it work.
Please a little help. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the JavaScript `setInterval` function. You may also wish to consider using a CSS animation instead of jQuery.

Comment: The code should be refactored. Variables like widths and heights should be calculated only once, not at each call. If you need to refresh them, add a listener on the window's resize event.
At which rate do you want your animation to run (how much calls per second?)

Comment: `or here` is your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/fzj0m52j/

Comment: I really thought this needed some explanations and optimization.

Comment: [Just for fun](http://jsfiddle.net/5t44wvdh/22/) use animate property instead of CSS.

Answer (score 3):

First, refactor so that you don't compute widths and heights at every function call.

Then use setInterval to call a function every `n` milliseconds :

```
jQuery(function($) {
     // No need for document.ready cause jQuery is made to execute this function when the doc is ready.
     // initialize variables
     var $div = $('#test'),
     delay = 1000, // ms
     docHeight,
     docWidth,
     divWidth,
     divHeight,
     heightMax,
     widthMax;
     function onResize(){
         //update them
         docHeight = $(document).height();
         docWidth = $(document).width();
         divWidth = $div.width();
         divHeight = $div.height();
         heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
         widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;
     }
     function loop_pos(){
         $div.css({
            left: Math.floor(Math.random()*widthMax),
            top: Math.floor(Math.random()*heightMax)
            // here
         });
      }
      // Calculate for the first time
      onResize();
      // Add event listener
      $(window).resize(onResize);
      // run loop
      setInterval(loop_pos, delay); // 1000 ms = 1 second
});
```

See fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/5f4quu8u/

Answer (score 1):

`"or here"` is your answer, just refactor your code to prevent running your DOM for sizes when it's not needed:

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/fzj0m52j/5/)***

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $div = $('#test'), x, y;

    function getSizes(){
        x = $(document).width() - $div.width();
        y = $(document).height() - $div.height();
    } 
    function loop_pos(){
        $div.css({ // or use `.animate` instead of `.css`
            left: ~~(Math.random() * x),
            top:  ~~(Math.random() * y)
        });
    }

    getSizes();                         // Get them immediately
    $("window").on("resize", getSizes); // Update values on Win. resize
    setInterval(loop_pos, 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would first move your code outside the $(document).ready()-part and declare it as a separate function.

```
function moveDiv(){
   var docHeight = $(document).height();
   docWidth = $(document).width();
   $div = $('#test');
   divWidth = $div.width();
   divHeight = $div.height();
   heightMax = docHeight - divHeight;
   widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

   $div.css({
       left: Math.floor(Math.random()*widthMax),
       top: Math.floor(Math.random()*heightMax)
   });
}
```

Then you can use the SetInterval-function in javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var delay = 1*1000; //would move the div every 1 second
    setInterval( moveDiv , delay );
});
```

That should do it I think. (Given that your code works which it seems to me it should!)